# need to extract table formatted data form the text file without hardcoding it

Tags: json, python-3.x, text-files

I have this data in text file, i need only table formatted info and that will be convert into JSON.

### VRF: iNET

BGP VRF iNET, state: Active
BGP Route Distinguisher: 65500:660001
VRF ID: 0x60000002
BGP router identifier 172.23.0.166, local AS number 65500
Non-stop routing is enabled
BGP table state: Active
Table ID: 0xe0000002   RD version: 163269134
BGP main routing table version 163269134
BGP NSR Initial initsync version 711918 (Reached)
BGP NSR/ISSU Sync-Group versions 163269134/0

BGP is operating in STANDALONE mode.

Process       RcvTblVer   bRIB/RIB   LabelVer  ImportVer  SendTblVer  StandbyVer
Speaker       163269134  163269134  163269134  163269134   163269134   163269134

Neighbor        Spk    AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ  Up/Down  St/PfxRcd
72.14.218.108     0 15169       0       0        0    0    0 00:00:00 Idle
72.14.243.25      0 15169       0       0        0    0    0 00:00:00 Idle
74.125.49.141     0 15169 1529609 1441333 163269134    0    0    1y19w       3572
157.238.179.41    0  2914 180902357 1442424 163269134    0    0     7w4d     361703
193.108.155.11    0 21357  720787  723782 163269134    0    0     2w3d          0
196.3.74.214      0  6400  720644 31280926 163269134    0    0    12w6d          0
196.3.81.10       0 65500  720387 63829459 163269134    0    0     4w4d          0

awaiting for response